# TPL - Reduce post latency

Tags: c#, .net, task-parallel-library

I'm building a web-scraper and it seems as though TPL is a good fit for my use case. Here's the flow I have in mind:

```
GetCommentsFromA --|                     |-- NotifyC
                   |-- ExtractKeywords --| 
GetCommentsFromB --|                     |-- NotifyD
```

Essentially, there are three types of components: collectors, transformers, and notifiers. The collectors collect comments by scraping different websites, and then pass along the comments to the transformers. They are expected to poll the webpage every X seconds. In this case the only transformer present is the one responsible for extracting keywords from the comments. They are essentially never-ending producers.

I originally implemented this by extending the classic Producer-Consumer model. I placed a buffer block between the collectors and transformer, and another between the transformer and the notifiers. (There's a bit more that's actually happening, but that's the jist.) Each component posted and received data from their corresponding buffer blocks independently. That said, I feel like there must be a more elegant approach.

Since then I discovered that `LinkTo` allows blocks to become interconnected, and that there are specialized blocks other than buffer blocks, so I've started to consider something along the following lines:

```
var extractKeywords = new TransformBlock<string, string>(ExtractKeywords);
var notifyTarget = new ActionBlock<string, string>(NotifyTarget);
extractKeywords.LinkTo(notifyTarget);
```

I could then spin up different collectors that more-or-less do the following on separate threads:

```
public async Task CollectAsync()
{
    while (true)
    {
        Page page = await website.DownloadLatestPageAsync();
        foreach (string comment in page.Comments())
        {
            transformer.Post(comment);
        }
        await Task.Delay(ArbitraryDelay);
    }
}
```

The collectors would be posting to the transform block seen in the earlier snippet. I do, however, have some reservations with this approach. Firstly, (and this could be due to my lack of familiarity with async, multi-threading and TPL,) I'm concerned that posting to the transform block will incur latency. Ideally, I want the collectors to spend as little time as possible transferring data to the transformer, but I can't seem to figure out a clean way of doing that. Calling `Post` seems to block for quite some time should the transformer be slow, and I'm not sure if `SendAsync` would handle this issue either. `Task.Run` seems like a bad idea... But I don't know. Feel like I'm close, but missing something simple.

Comment: 1) why is the download not part of the TPL DataFlow chain?  2) instead of posting comments you should post the URL into the head of the chain 3) add a new block at the beginning to perform the actual download of the page 4) after downloading, the block can split into comments, passing them onto the transform block 5) **get rid of the arbitrary delay** to remove your problem with _"latency"_

Comment: @MickyD Each collector is supposed to poll a website every X seconds/minutes for comments, which is intentional. That's why I inserted that delay

Comment: In that case Rx framework might be a better fit.

Comment: @MickyD Any particular resources you'd recommend to learn about Rx as it pertains to my use-case? I've started reading through this: https://github.com/LeeCampbell/RxCookbook/blob/master/Repository/Polling.md

Comment: Certainly good sir, check out this site http://introtorx.com/Content/v1.0.10621.0/01_WhyRx.html.  I found it rather good